# Handling oracle procedure error in unix file

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

In my application oracle procedure is currently called through unix script, when there is error in exception block we are handling something like this :-

```
PROC_LOGS('<PROC_NAME>', <TABLE_NAME>, 'Exception','Exception occured - '||SQLERRM);
```

PROC_LOG does nothing but inserts entry into log table but we need now to catch that error in unix also (return some value except 0) from where is it called so remaining process can be terminated best on that, what is the best way to do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE....
...
DECLARE
....
BEGIN
..
...
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
PROC_LOGS('<PROC_NAME>', <TABLE_NAME>, 'EXCEPTION','EXCEPTION OCCURED - '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Unix script part from where I m calling procedure

```
sqlplus <<-!
$US/$P@$I
set serveroutput on
@$SQL/execute_proc.sql $1 $2
```

`execue_proc` contains something like this :-

```
 define IN_1 = '&1';
  define IN_2 = '&2';

spool $SQL/test_&&IN
declare
 P_IN_TABLE_NAME varchar2(250) := '&&IN_TABLE_NAME';
 P_IN_REGION varchar2(250) := '&&IN_REGION';
begin
PROC_UPDATE_CHARGE_FACT(P_IN_TABLE_NAME,P_IN_REGION);
    end;

/
spool off
```

Comment: please post a snippet of your proc which shows the exception handling.

Comment: I have added the snippet of proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`raise`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/raise_statement.htm) the exception, like this:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    PROC_LOGS('<PROC_NAME>', <TABLE_NAME>, 'EXCEPTION','EXCEPTION OCCURED - '||SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
END;
```

or use `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    PROC_LOGS('<PROC_NAME>', <TABLE_NAME>, 'EXCEPTION','EXCEPTION OCCURED - '||SQLERRM);
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'An unexpected exception occurred.');
END;
```

Comment: I have added the unix script which is invoking oracle procedure script part in question.. Is there is any way to do this without touching oracle procedure part? preferably through unix script

Comment: No, if your database proc is not raising the exception then I don't believe there is any way you can tell if it has failed on the client side (unless you query the log table which is not a good approach).

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably calling SQL*Plus, and SQL*Plus has a configuration item that should help.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve052.htm#BACHCFEF

Since you probably execute the procedure from an anonymous block, the error should propagate to SQL*Plus and "WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE" will return the relevant error code to the unix environment.

Comment: I have added the unix script which is invoking oracle procedure script part in question

Comment: As @dogbane says,just raise the error after logging it with proc_log, and use this configuration of SQL*Plus to propagate the error back to unix

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to have proc_log() to also write to a log file and then have the unix script to check the log file.